# Por que o HttpClient BaseAddres não está funcionando?

Tags: c#

Abaixo meu codigo:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:porta/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // ESSA LINHA DA O ERRO
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/User/ObterTodosPorId/" + id);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (data != null)
        {
            var varUsuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioModel>(data);
            usuario = varUsuario;
        }
    }
};
```

Estou tentando fazer um GET em http://localhost:porta/api/User/ObterTodosPorId/1 (id = 1 exemplo)

Mas quando bate na linha que comentei ali no codigo, não acontece nenhum erro, o sistema continua e a lista que seria preenchida com esses dados fica em branco. (ja testei com um preenchimento local e funcionou).

Comment: O comentário diz "_ESSA LINHA DA O ERRO_", mas na pergunta você diz "_não acontece nenhum erro_". Afinal, tem um erro ou não tem?

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor esse erro que aconteceu ?
Poderia mostrar a stack trace do erro ?

Comment: Fiz alguns testes hoje de manha, identifiquei que a porta do local host estava incorreta, alterei e funcionou, obrigado.... De todo caso, não aparecia nenhum erro, nada, ele so continuava a execução do sistema...